# matlab select vector from matrix and hide single dimensions

Tags: performance, matlab, vector, matrix, slice

How can I select some parts of an matrix and cut the single dimensions?

Example: B = zeros(100,100,3,'double');

When I select B(2,3,:) I get a `1x1x3` matrix as result - this is not the expected result, because for some operations (like norm) I need a vector as result. To handle this problem I used `squeeze`, but this operations seems to be very time consuming, especially when heavily used.

How can I select only the vector and 'cut' the single dimensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you could use the colon operator, like this:

```
x = B(2,3,:);
x = x(:);
```

This places all elements of X into a number-of-elements by 1 vector.

Comment: What's the speed difference like between this and `squeeze`?

Answer (score 0):

You could also permute the dimensions to bring the non-singleton one to front. Either:

```
>> permute(B(2,3,:),[3 1 2])
ans =
      0.97059
      0.69483
       0.2551
```

or

```
>> permute(B(2,3,:),[1 3 2])
ans =
      0.97059      0.69483       0.2551
```

depending on whether you want a row or a column vector.